# What condition of $\mathbf x$ can ensure $\mathbf A$ is full rank?

Tags: matrix-rank, positive-definite

$
\mathbf A =
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{c | c | c}
\mathbf D  &\pmb 1 &\mathbf x  \\ \hline
-\pmb 1^\top &0 &0  \\ \hline
-\mathbf x^\top &0 &0
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix},
$
where $\mathbf D \in \Bbb R^{l\times l}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, $\pmb 1\in\Bbb R^{l}=[1,1,\dots,1]^\top$ and $\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^{l}$.

I have tried with some random $x$, $A$
is always full rank. I have tried it in Matlab $100000$ times.

If $\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf D&\mathbf x  \\
-\mathbf x^\top &0
\end{bmatrix}$, then we can easily prove it.

Since $\mathbf D$ has inverse, for any $\mathbf x$, we have
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf D&\mathbf x  \\
-\mathbf x^\top &0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf I &-\mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x  \\
\varnothing &1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf D&\varnothing  \\
-\mathbf x^\top &\mathbf x^\top\mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x.
\end{bmatrix}
$

Taking the determinant of both sides, we obtain
$
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf D&\mathbf x  \\
-\mathbf x^\top &0
\end{vmatrix}
=|\mathbf D|\cdot |\mathbf x^\top\mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x|.
$

Since $\mathbf D^{-1}$ is positive definite, $|\mathbf x^\top\mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x|$ is nonzero.
This means the determinant of $\mathbf A$ is nonzero, and then $rank(\mathbf  A)=l+1$ without any other condition.

But after adding the term $\pmb 1$, I don't know how to do it.

If
$
\mathbf A =
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{c | c | c}
\mathbf D  &\pmb 1 &\mathbf x  \\ \hline
-\pmb 1^\top &0 &0  \\ \hline
-\mathbf x^\top &0 &0
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix},
$
Similarly, we can deduce that
$
|\mathbf D|\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
\pmb 1^\top \mathbf D^{-1}\pmb 1 &\pmb 1^\top \mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x  \\
\pmb 1^\top \mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x &\mathbf x^\top \mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x
\end{vmatrix} 
=|\mathbf D|\cdot|\pmb 1^\top \mathbf D^{-1}(\pmb 1 \mathbf x^\top-\mathbf x\pmb 1^\top)\mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x|.
$

Hence we need
$
\pmb 1^\top \mathbf D^{-1}(\pmb 1 \mathbf x^\top-\mathbf x\pmb 1^\top)\mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf x \neq 0
$.

Can we say that as long as $\mathbf x\neq k \pmb 1$ $(k\in \Bbb R)$, then A is full rank?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128768/discussion-on-question-by-hao-wang-what-condition-of-mathbf-x-can-ensure-ma).